# Execute C# Application as an Administrator in Limited User Account

Tags: c#, auto-update, admin-rights, limited-user

I developed an application which updates itself like below

1. I will send the Signal to the Client Listener from Admin PC to update Client Application
2. Listener will Stop the Client Application and then Delete the Client Application.
3. Listener will copy the latest Client Application from the Shared URL where New Client Application is residing.
4. After copying Listener will execute the Client Application and will notify the Admin Application about the Update success.

I made this system so that without client knowledge my application will update itself.

Above system is running perfectly in Clients with Admin rights. But it is not working in Clients with limited access.

In limited access Client PC, Listener Application is not able to delete the Client Application to copy the latest Application.

Please help me, what to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a custom windows service, your listener, that receives the signal from the admin pc and updates your client application in background.

Comment: Windows service an not delete files on C drive. I think its a limitation of Windows Service.

Comment: Which identity you use to run the service? Using LocalSystem account there is not limitations. If you still can not delete the file then it probably is in use.